# Custom google search does not return any results

Tags: javascript, google-custom-search

i have a problem with custom google search.
i copy code from custom google search engine and paste it in my project.
for  one domain it works and return results but for another sub domain it not works and not returned any results

Does anyone have an idea why?

One page has a search box only with code:

```
<div  id="cse-search-form"  dir="<%= MyBase.UserPreferences.DisplayDir%>" style="width:500px;"></div>
                           <script>
                               (function () {
                                   var cx = '017015442779235202717:g8u07nzbkmi';
                                   var gcse = document.createElement('script');
                                   gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
                                   gcse.async = true;
                                   gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') + '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
                                   var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                                   s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
                               })();
                        </script>
                        <gcse:searchbox-only resultsUrl="SearchResults.aspx"></gcse:searchbox-only>
```

And the results are displayed on another page with code:

```
<div>
    <script>
        (function () {
            var cx = '017015442779235202717:g8u07nzbkmi';
            var gcse = document.createElement('script');
            gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
            gcse.async = true;
            gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') + '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
        })();
    </script>
    <gcse:searchresults-only></gcse:searchresults-only>
```

Additionally,
I tried to put the search box and results on the same page with the following code:

```
 <div>Compact Layout Demo</div>
 <div id="cse-search-form" style="width: 500px;">Loading</div>

<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   google.load('search', '1', { language: 'en' });
   google.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
   var customSearchControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl   ('017015442779235202717:g8u07nzbkmi');
    customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.SMALL_CSE_RESULTSET);
    customSearchControl.draw('cse-search-form');

    // var options = new google.search.DrawOptions();
    // options.enableSearchboxOnly("http://www.tiemponeto.com/All/searchresults3.asp");
    // customSearchControl.draw('cse-search-form', options)
}, true);
```

Search still not working and not seeing results

Please, who can help me?

Comment: May be google has not crawled your second domain yet?

Comment: From where have you obtained these codes. As far as I have used, google mini search is available for a particular domain search only. You need to register for second domain seperately to get its results.

Answer (score 0):

The public url for your search engine brings results, e.g. for the query "office":
https://www.google.com/cse/publicurl?cx=017015442779235202717:g8u07nzbkmi

This means that the engine is working in general.

First of all, check the "Look and feel" tab of your CSE Control Panel. You are trying to have searchbox and searchresults display separately, so you need to select the "two page" option (one page with the searchbox and second with the results) and save the new configuration.

Secondly, make sure that your SearchResults.aspx script append the "q=" parameter when redirecting user to the results page (e.g. ?q=office). The  element on that page reads this param from the url and displays results for the included query ("office").

Comment: The site is  not perfect still.

Comment: i have two domain in my account.One of them works and the other does not. i defined two domain  in account for search test. all results you see about test domain and mysite search not work.

Comment: the scrip is good. the url for the query "sms": SearchResults.aspx?%D7%97%D7%A4%D7%A9=sms .

Comment: i have added the plus.google.com ,facebook.com,twitter.com,linkedin.com
urls to custom search.the query if searched in google iam getting all proper result from google.but custom search engine i cant.please let me know 
@Devnook

Answer (score 0):

The name of the domain/domains you are searching is set in the custom search engine options. You need to create a **second** custom search engine, go to **setup** and set the domain name there, under the **Sites to Search** heading. Then you use for the code the second search engine for your subdomain.

The second search engine will have very slightly different code, this line will have a different search engine ID:

```
var cx = '017015442779235202717:g8u07nzbkmi';
```

You can tell the first search engine is restricted and not searching all the internet, because *office* returns results but other terms don't, eg *chair*.